# Wordpress RSS error on valid RSS feeds

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I'm running into a really weird error that has me at a loss. I'm working on a wordpress site and I'm trying to read from an RSS feed but I keep getting

> Error RSS: This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: Mismatched tag at line 12, column 8

The problem is that I have checked the RSS feed on https://validator.w3.org/feed/ and it is a valid feed. The same thing has happened with other feed sources, and oddly sometimes is has coincided that the error is also at line 12, column 8. Not only that, if I keep hitting the refresh button on the browser the line 12 changes to line 109 sometimes and then back again to 12. But wait, there's more, one of the feeds that I'm testing doesn't even have more than 100 lines and it stills shows the error on line 109 sometimes. Also this same feed on line 12 only has this: `<item>`, which means there's no column 8. I've tested this on 3 separate installations of Wordpress, using different themes and different plugins, but the same version of Wordpress, 4.7. Anybody has a clue on what might be going on.

Edit: As requested in the comments here's the RSS code in question

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <channel>
        <title>Online Resource Portal</title>
        <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=Home</link>
        <description>Channel Description</description>
        <atom:link href='http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=RSS' rel='self' type='application/rss+xml' />
        <language>es-es</language>
        <pubDate>Thu, 19 Oct 2017 12:00:00 -0400</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Mon, 10 Apr 2017 12:00:00 -0400</lastBuildDate>
        <docs>http://www.rssboard.org/rss-2-0-1</docs>
        <item>
            <title>Laboratorio Clínico</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=6</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=6</guid>
            <description>Laboratorio Clínico</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Familia y Juventud</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=5</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=5</guid>
            <description>Familia y Juventud</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Diabetes Mellitus en el Embarazo</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=4</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=4</guid>
            <description>Diabetes Mellitus en el Embarazo</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Baja Visión</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=3</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=3</guid>
            <description>Baja Visión</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Glaucoma</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=2</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=2</guid>
            <description>Glaucoma</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Adulto Mayor</title>
            <link>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=1</link>
            <guid>http://www.myurl.local/index.php?P=FullRecord&#x26;ResourceId=1</guid>
            <description>Adulto Mayor</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 31 Dec 1969 07:00:00 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I had to change the urls to www.myurl.local cause I wasn't allowed to publish the actual URL. Also the feed is published on an internal network.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the RSS feed?

Comment: Some code and/or the rss feed would be helpful

Comment: I've edited the question to add some insight, as you requested. Thanks for your interest